# How is the law of total probability used in deriving absorption probabilities?

Tags: probability, definition

In this online book in this link under absorption probabilities:

https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_2_5_using_the_law_of_total_probability_with_recursion.php

> How ***explicitly*** is the law of total probability used to get $$a_i
>  = \sum_ka_kp_{ik}$$

This seems to show that $$P(\text{absorption in 0 | $X_0 = i$}) = \sum_k P(\text{absorption in 0 | $X_0 = k$})*P(X_1 = k | X_0 = i)$$

Under normal total probability $$P(A) = \sum_k P(A|B_k)P(B_k)$$ where $B_k$ is a member of the partition of the sample space.

***What is the sample space here?  What is the partition?***

It seems like $$A=(\text{absorption in 0 | $X_0=i$}) \text{ and } B_k = (X_1=k | X_0=i)$$ but then we would have $$A|B_k = \biggl(\text{absorption in 0 | $X_0=i $}\biggr) \space\text{$|$}\space \biggl(X_1=k | X_0=i \biggr)$$ which I don't see how reduces to
$$P(\text{absorption in 0 | $X_0 = k$})$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_0=\{\text{absobtion in 0}\}$. Then

\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(A_0\mid X_0=i)&=\frac{\mathsf{P}(A_0, X_0=i)}{\mathsf{P}(X_0=i)} \\
&=\sum_k \frac{\mathsf{P}(A_0, X_0=i,X_1=k)}{\mathsf{P}(X_0=i)} \\
&=\sum_k \mathsf{P}(A_0\mid X_1=k, X_0=i)\mathsf{P}(X_1=k\mid X_0=i) \\
&=\sum_k \mathsf{P}(A_0\mid X_1=k)\mathsf{P}(X_1=k\mid X_0=i),
\end{align}
where the 4th line follows from the Markov property. Namely, let $\tau_0:=\inf\{n\ge 1:X_n=0\}$. Then $A_0=\{\tau_0<\infty\}$ and
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(A_0\mid X_1=k,X_0=i)&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(\tau_0=n\mid X_1=k,X_0=i) \\
&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(X_n=0,X_{n-1}\ne 0,\ldots\mid X_1=k,X_0=i) \\
&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(X_n=0,X_{n-1}\ne 0,\ldots\mid X_1=k) \\
&=\mathsf{P}(A_0\mid X_1=k),
\end{align}
where the 3rd line follows form the Markov property (sometimes it's called the Extended Markov property, i.e. $\{X_n,X_{n+1},\ldots\}$ is conditionally independent on $\{X_0,\ldots, X_{n-1}\}$ given $X_n$. See, for example, Theorem 4.1.5 in [these notes](http://web.math.ku.dk/noter/filer/beting.pdf)).

Comment: How did you get the second line?  What property allows you to sum the entire expression and add another variable in the upper probability alone?

Comment: This is what you called "normal total probability":
$$
\mathsf{P}(A) = \sum_k \mathsf{P}(A\mid B_k)\mathsf{P}(B_k) = \sum_k \mathsf{P}(A,B_k)
$$

Comment: How does the Markov property apply from the third to the fourth line?  The markov property states $P(X_{m+1} = j | X_m=i, X_{m-1} = i_{m-1}, ..., X_0=i_{0}) = P(X_{m+1} = j | X_m = i)$.  This just applies to successive increments of time ($m$ and $m+1$) while $A_0$ could by any time increment.

Comment: If $\tau_0$ is the infimum of that set, then it's a single element.  So isn't $A_0=\{\tau_0 < \infty \}$ just a set containing a single number?

Comment: $\tau_0$ is a random variable (possibly taking infinite value).

Comment: I don't understand your notation.  What does $\tau_0 = \text{inf}\{n \ge 1 : X_n = 0\}$ say in words?  To me that says the infimum of the set of all numbers greater than or equal to $1$ such that $X_n=0$ equals $\tau_0$.

Comment: If $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathsf{P})$ is the underlying probability space, then
$$
\tau_0(\omega)=\inf\{n\ge 1:X_n(\omega)=0\} \quad \omega\in \Omega,
$$
i.e. for each $\omega$ it gives a single number. In words, $\tau_0$ is the [first hit time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitting_time) of $\{0\}$.

Comment: Nice. (+1) IMHO, definition of $P(\text{Absorption in}\, 0 | X_) = k)$ in the link is shamefully vague. You have cleaned that up. // For application, need to recall that states 0 and 3 are absorbing and that states 1 and 2 are transient. // In link, equations below key eqn with summation are easier to interpret intuitively.

Comment: @BruceET Can you give a better definition of what that means?  I'm still having trouble following.

Comment: @d.k.o. There is a definition 4.5.1 but there is no theorem 4.5.1 in the paper you included.

Comment: @OliverG: The condition need not specify step 0. More like given you're at a particular transient state at any given step, what is the probability of ever getting to state 0, hence being absorbed there.

Comment: Usual concept and notation: 'first passage time' $f_{ij}.$ Your book seems to prefer intuition and 'arm waving' (not a crime in a course for engrs or managers at basic level) over formal notation and proof. If you want to nail down the proofs, maybe look a a book on Markov Chains, a book on Stochastic Processes with a reasonable treatment of MCs, or google.

Comment: @OliverG It's 4.1.5 on page 75

Comment: @d.k.o. Can you explicitly explain how the third line of the second block of equations follows from the Markov property on that page?  I don't understand how $P(X_1, ..., X_n, X_{n+1}, ... | x_n) = P(X_n, X_{n-1}, ... | X_n)P(X_n+1, X_{n+1}, ...)$ allows you to eliminate a conditional from the equation.

Comment: Suppose you have 3 events $A,B$, and $C$. Then if $A$ is conditionally independent of $C$ given $B$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(A\mid B,C)=\frac{\mathsf{P}(A,C\mid B)}{\mathsf{P}(C\mid B)}=\frac{\mathsf{P}(A\mid B)\mathsf{P}(C\mid B)}{\mathsf{P}(C\mid B)}=\mathsf{P}(A\mid B).
$$